# Do I have authority to display images according to Terms of Use?

Tags: intellectual-property, terms-of-service

In my Android app submitting for approval I am using [OMDBApi.com](http://www.omdbapi.com) and showing movie posters were retrieving from their Api. According to [Terms of Use](http://www.omdbapi.com/legal.htm) do I have the authority to display content?

How can I provide to Google I do not violate any intellectual property?

google says:

I had to reject it because of an **unauthorized use of copyrighted content**.

Remove any content owned by a third party from your app. For exmaple; your app's store listing contains **official images of Thor in the Phone Screenshots** and Feature Graphics
Read through the [Unauthorized Use of Copyrighted Content](https://play.google.com/about/spam.html#impersonation-intellectual-property:unauthorized-use-of-copyrighted-content) article for more details and examples.
Make sure your app is compliant with the [Impersonation and Intellectual Property policy](https://play.google.com/about/spam.html#impersonation-intellectual-property) and all other policies listed in the Developer Program Policies. Remember that additional enforcement could occur if there are further policy issues with your apps.
Sign in to your Developer Console and submit your app.

This is how cover photo how app look like.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think you haven't violated copyright?

As far as I can see, omdbapi.com says that their content is contributed by their users - that means that they (probably) do not have the permission of the copyright holders and are violating copyright themselves.

If you buy something from a thief, you don't own it.